# Setting a password hint on administrator account in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, domain-controller, password, user-accounts

I've tried to change a password on administrator account using `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\User Accounts\Change Your Password` but can't set a password hint. When I clicked `What is a password hint` I could read

> "Because your computer is on a domain, you can't create a password
>   hint."

Then I've opened computer properties and saw that the computer belong to workgroup only not a domain. Then I've run `gpresult /v` and it has printed a domain name which is a computer name and `<Local Computer>`. Could you explain it, I want to know if my computer belong to a domain or not as I don't remember if I configured PDC when installed the server or not? Also I don't have `Active Directory Services` role added to the server roles. And how to get information about domain controlles without adding ADS role?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like an absolute mess. Firstly, there's no such thing as PDC and hasn't been for many years. Either you created a domain by adding the ADS role, you joined a domain, or you didn't. I find it bizarre that you can't remember if you built a Domain Controller or not.

If the computer properties shows it's in a workgroup, then that's where it is. For some purposes, it will take the local computer name as a "Domain Name" in lieu of being connected to an external Active Directory Domain.

For example, `gpresult /v` shows the following on my non-domain laptop:

```
RSOP data for DAN-LAPTOP\Dan on DAN-LAPTOP : Logging Mode
----------------------------------------------------------

OS Configuration:            Standalone Workstation
OS Version:                  6.2.9200
Site Name:                   N/A
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               C:\Users\Dan
Connected over a slow link?: No
```

I know this doesn't really help you, but why on *Earth* would you want to set a password hint?

---

Check this page: Start Menu -> Right Click on "Computer" -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Computer Name -> Change

This is your definitive answer on whether that machine is joined to a domain or not

[image]

Comment: Thanks, if it has any logic I wouldn't ask this question. I searched the net and can't find a suitable answer. PDC (Primary Domain Controller) seems to be on the server. I have not added ADS role. I have only DHCP, DNS, Remote Accces an Routing roles. "in lieu of being connected to an external Active Directory Domain" don't understand, I didn't connect to any external domain, it's a local server which has a external interface.

Comment: The computer properties are correct - perhaps you could post a screenshot.

Comment: What a properties are you talking, don't understand.

Comment: I've added the detail to the answer

Comment: yes, I have the same picture, but `gpresult` shows a domain name, and password hint is not working due to the message above.

Comment: @RomanC please provide screenshots of both